# How can I rotate the output in 90 degrees?

Tags: c

I have a code and from `kladblok.txt` there is a file with the following numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How can i get the output :

```
1111111111
2222222222
```

etc..

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is this homework?  It sounds like homework.  If this is homework, then it should be tagged as homework as is appropriate for homework questions.  Homework.

Comment: ahhh sorry.. first time using this site..

Comment: Show us what have you already tried. If you want to get real help with your code, you must make some effort.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void koptekst(void);
void draaien (FILE*, FILE*);

int main (void)

    {
         int input;

         printf("\t Kies Menu: \n\n");
         printf("\t++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
         printf("\t+ 2. Kopieer Tekst Bestand       +\n");
         printf("\t+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n");

         printf ("Voer uw keuze in:\n");
         scanf ("%d", &input);
         system ("cls");

Comment: switch (input)
                {

                case 2:
                    koptekst();
                    break;

                }
    }

   void koptekst (void)
    {

Comment: there is someway i can't paste my text

Comment: @user967941, click the Edit link at the bottom of your question and paste the text in there. After pasting, select it and click the button marked `{}` at the top of the edit pane, which will format the code correctly for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print it rotated 90 degrees, then just change the start/end/increment of your loops.  Say you have `int data[10][10]` in the original rotation.

Then you want to start in the lower left and go up.  Move right one space, start again at the bottom and go to the top, etc:

```
int i, j;

for (i = ?; i ? ?; i??)
{
    for (j = ?; j ? ?; j??)
    {
        /* print element [i][j] (or perhaps [j][i]) */
    }

    /* do a carriage return here */
}

/* What should the question marks be? */
```

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is very simple:

- Open the file
- Allocate a 2 dimensional array which is big enough to contain the numbers
- Read the numbers to the array
- Close the file
- Print the array transposed
- Free the array